# Steady State case for differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, parameters

I need to write these equations in steady state form (time derivatives set to 0), and then substitute in values for the parameters (e,d,q,f). However, I don't understand how to do this as if I set the derivatives to 0, when solving the equations, the parameters no longer appear?

```
e x'[t] == (1 - x[t])*x[t] + q y[t] - 
   x[t] y[t]
d y'[t] == -q y[t] - x[t] y[t] + 
   2 f z[t] 
z'[t] == x[t] - z[t]
```

Answer (score 1):

The equations reduce to algebraic :

```
{0 == (1 - x)*x + q y - x y,
0 == -q - x y + 2 f z,
0 == x - z}
```

You can use Solve or NSolve.

Comment: I'd divide both sides by `d` and `e` first, to not lose them when you set `x'[t]` and `y'[t]` to zero.

Comment: @ChrisK How does that make any difference? Once you start solving the equations, you multiply by `d` and `e` and they're gone again.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Umm, good point :)  Maybe I was thinking ahead to a stability analysis, where `d` and `e` would matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try rule `/. _'[t]->0`

```
eqn = {e x'[t] == (1 - x[t])*x[t] + q y[t] - x[t] y[t],d y'[t] == -q y[t] - x[t] y[t] + 2 f z[t],z'[t] == x[t] - z[t]} /. _'[t]->0
(*{0 == (1 - x[t]) x[t] + q y[t] - x[t] y[t], 0 == -q y[t] - x[t] y[t] + 2 f z[t], 0 == x[t] - z[t]}*)
```

These equations might be solved  for  `{x[t],y[t],z[t]}`

The two parameters `e,d` are irrelevant for the solution!